# UnboundLocalError en python 3.7.6(anaconda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

estoy haciendo un "juego" que genera una tabla al azar y tu tienes que poner el numero que da

pero me sale este error al modificar una variable de puntos

```
File "C:\Users\*mi usuario*\tablas.py", line 27, in main
    buenas += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'buenas' referenced before assignment
```

este es mi codigo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Apr  4 13:58:03 2020

@author: me
"""

import time
from random import randrange



def tablas():
    num = int(input("pon el numero de la tabla> "))
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{num} X {i} = {i * num}")


def main():
    numero1 = randrange(1, 10)
    numero2 = randrange(1, 10)
    print(f"cuanto es {numero1} X {numero2}?")
    calc = int(input("Cual es el resultado?> "))
    if calc == numero1 * numero2:
        print(f"lo lograste! {calc} era el numero")
        time.sleep(1)
        buenas += 1
        print(buenas)
    else:
        print("lo siento pero erraste al numero :( ")
        time.sleep(1)
    if buenas == 5:
        print(f"conseguiste {buenas} de 5")


while True:       
    print("generador de tablas aleatorias y las tablas")
    print("""
tablas(1)
desafio(2)
salir(3)    
""")

    opc = input("(1/2/3)> ")

    if opc == "1":
        tablas()

    elif opc == "2":
        for i in range(1,6):
            buenas = 0
            main()
    elif opc == "3":
        print("Saliendo...")
        time.sleep(1)
        exit()

    else:
        print(f"{opc} no es un comando")
```

por lo que veo el programa me dice que la variable es asignada antes que la función pero yo la asigno antes de que se ejecute.
se aceptan arreglos de código,por favor no mejoren "mi código" haciendo otro

Answer (score 0):

Lo que indica el error es se intenta referenciar a una variable y reasignare un nuevo objeto además antes de que sea declarada.

> pero yo la asigno antes de que se ejecute

Correcto, lo haces en:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    buenas = 0
    main()
```

pero aquí declaras `buenas` como una variable global (a nivel de módulo), en cambio en la función no le indicas que esta variable es global. Puedes acceder a variables globales desde una función, lo que no puedes es reasignarles un nuevo objeto (`int` es inmutable) sin declararla como global en la función. En el momento que intentas reasignar se intenta usar una variable local. Podrías indicar que trate a `buenas` como variable global con global total dentro de la función `main`:

```
def main():
    global buenas
    #...
```

No obstante, las variables globales deben evitarse siempre que sea posible.  Dado que `buenas` solo la usa la función, por lo que debería ser una variable local sin más. Declarala en `main` antes del `for` y ya está. Si necesitaras conocer su valor fuera, siempre podrías retornarla.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Apr  4 13:58:03 2020

@author: me
"""

import time
from random import randrange



def tablas():
    num = int(input("pon el numero de la tabla> "))
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{num} X {i} = {i * num}")


def main():
    numero1 = randrange(1, 10)
    numero2 = randrange(1, 10)
    print(f"cuanto es {numero1} X {numero2}?")
    calc = int(input("Cual es el resultado?> "))
    buenas = 0
    if calc == numero1 * numero2:
        print(f"lo lograste! {calc} era el numero")
        time.sleep(1)
        buenas += 1
        print(buenas)
    else:
        print("lo siento pero erraste al numero :( ")
        time.sleep(1)
    if buenas == 5:
        print(f"conseguiste {buenas} de 5")


while True:       
    print("generador de tablas aleatorias y las tablas")
    print("""
tablas(1)
desafio(2)
salir(3)    
""")

    opc = input("(1/2/3)> ")

    if opc == "1":
        tablas()

    elif opc == "2":
        for i in range(1,6):
            main()
    elif opc == "3":
        print("Saliendo...")
        time.sleep(1)
        exit()

    else:
        print(f"{opc} no es un comando")
```